# DevExress XtraGrid MouseDown Event does not fire second time

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid, mousedown

I have the MouseDown Event on my XtraGrid, that doesn't want to fire the second time on the same column.

It recognizes the first click, but unless I click another column or row before attempting to click the original row/column, nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?  Here is the code in the MouseDown event:

```
         var hitInfo = gridViewSpecialty.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
         if (hitInfo.InRowCell)
         {
             int nRow = hitInfo.RowHandle;
             GridColumn column = hitInfo.Column;
             LinkClick(nRow, column);

         }
```

Thanks!!  Bob

Comment: What event is the above code in?

Comment: gridView_MouseDown event.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely due to the event erroring out.  I'd be willing to bet if you put a `Try{}catch{}` around that statement, you may trap the error.

Here's what I use when trying to capture a user click event with a grid.  I use the double-click event, like so:

```
private void gcMainGrid_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GridControl gc = (GridControl)sender;
        DevExpress.Utils.DXMouseEventArgs dxMEA = (DevExpress.Utils.DXMouseEventArgs)e;
        GridView gv = (GridView)gc.MainView;
        int iRowHandle = gv.CalcHitInfo(dxMEA.X, dxMEA.Y).RowHandle;

        //Check to see if the user is on a row.
    if (iRowHandle >= 0)
    {
        //Do something here.
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            Debugger.Break();
        else
            throw(ex);
    }
}
```

That will get me the RowHandle of the row that the user clicks on.  I think that's what you're after but I wouldn't use the mouse-down event for that.